# ASP.Net MVC2 page render takes up 70% CPU

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-2

I am doing stress tests on my ASP.Net MVC2 application, and I have set

`<compilation debug="false" />` in web.config.

Simulating 200 connections in the IIS7, which hosts this application, the CPU load goes up to 100%.  Simulated requests only access simple home page without the database operations.

Meanwhile, I run the `dotTrace` to profile the application,  which shows the page render procedure (like `RenderControl`, `RenderControlInternal`, etc.....) takes about 69% CPU time.

Is this normal?  How many connections can an MVC2 application support for one machine?

Comment: Are you using a single machine to do all this: host the application, run dotTrace and simulating 200 connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is absolutely not normal. I think there may be some other issues, but mvc2 spent more time to find related view when you return from action. Some things to do:

Update your libraries. Give view name from action and try again.

```
public ActionResult Index() {
     ///other operations
     return View("Index",yourmodel);
}
```

etc.